# Include the post type before the title of search results

Tags: functions, search

How can I add the 'Post Type' (Blog, Page) before the titles of search results?

Post type: Title

Example: Search results for "Potato"

Blog: How to cook the perfect potato!

Page: Sweet Potatoes

etc..

Thanks!

### Contents of my index.php

```
<?php
        if ( have_posts() ) :
            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                $post_format = et_pb_post_format(); ?>

                <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( 'et_pb_post' ); ?>>

            <?php
                $thumb = '';

                $width = (int) apply_filters( 'et_pb_index_blog_image_width', 1080 );

                $height    = (int) apply_filters( 'et_pb_index_blog_image_height', 675 );
                $classtext = 'et_pb_post_main_image';
                $titletext = get_the_title();
                $alttext   = get_post_meta( get_post_thumbnail_id(), '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true );
                $thumbnail = get_thumbnail( $width, $height, $classtext, $alttext, $titletext, false, 'Blogimage' );
                $thumb     = $thumbnail["thumb"];

                et_divi_post_format_content();

                if ( ! in_array( $post_format, array( 'link', 'audio', 'quote' ) ) ) {
                    if ( 'video' === $post_format && false !== ( $first_video = et_get_first_video() ) ) :
                        printf(
                            '<div class="et_main_video_container">
                                %1$s
                            </div>',
                            et_core_esc_previously( $first_video )
                        );
                    elseif ( ! in_array( $post_format, array( 'gallery' ) ) && 'on' === et_get_option( 'divi_thumbnails_index', 'on' ) && '' !== $thumb ) : ?>
                        <a class="entry-featured-image-url" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                            <?php print_thumbnail( $thumb, $thumbnail["use_timthumb"], $titletext, $width, $height ); ?>
                        </a>
                <?php
                    elseif ( 'gallery' === $post_format ) :
                        et_pb_gallery_images();
                    endif;
                } ?>

            <?php if ( ! in_array( $post_format, array( 'link', 'audio', 'quote' ) ) ) : ?>
                <?php if ( ! in_array( $post_format, array( 'link', 'audio' ) ) ) : ?>
                    <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php
                    et_divi_post_meta();

                    if ( 'on' !== et_get_option( 'divi_blog_style', 'false' ) || ( is_search() && ( 'on' === get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_et_pb_use_builder', true ) ) ) ) {
                        truncate_post( 270 );
                    } else {
                        the_content();
                    }
                ?>
            <?php endif; ?>

                </article> <!-- .et_pb_post -->
        <?php
                endwhile;

                if ( function_exists( 'wp_pagenavi' ) )
                    wp_pagenavi();
                else
                    get_template_part( 'includes/navigation', 'index' );
            else :
                get_template_part( 'includes/no-results', 'index' );
            endif;
        ?>
```

Comment: I guess "get_post_type" is what you are looking for
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_type/

Comment: Thank you. Being a php noob, how would I implement this within the search results? I assume some sort of if statment is_search() ? Sorry my php knowledge is limited!

Comment: You may have to share the relevant part of the search.php file in order to get a clear answer. probably something similar to: function echo_post_type( $post = null ) { $post = get_post( $post ); if ( $post ) { echo $post->post_type; } } echo_post_type( $post);

Comment: Thanks Julian I have discovered that the divi theme I am using doesn't have a search.php but I believe the index.php contains the relevant code. After some googling, I should be able to edit this by making a copy and renaming it search.php in my child theme? I have updated my post with the code. Thank you so much for your input.

Comment: The specifics of how you must/are able to implement a child theme vary from theme to theme, and even more so for massive theme frameworks like Divi. You will need to consult Divi's documentation and/or support channels for the proper approach. Another perhaps easier possibility might be to use a `the_title` filter hook and add the post type if the `! is_admin() && is_search()` predicates are `true`, assuming Divi is compatible with those hooks and conditions.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by copying the divi index.php and placing it in my child theme as search.php

I then found where the title and altered it with the below code:

```
<h2 class="entry-title">
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
<?php $post_type = get_post_type( $post->ID );
echo $post_type . ": ";
the_title(); ?>
</a>
</h2>
```

Probably not the correct way to do it but the result was perfect. My search results now have:

Blog: 'Blog title'

Page: 'Page title'

etc